# Prove the limit of the function with complicated domains.

Tags: calculus

Let $g$ be a function with domain, rational numbers defined by
$g(x) = \frac{2}{x-\sqrt{2}}$ for all rational $x$.
Prove that $$\lim_{x \to 0}g(x)= -\sqrt{2}$$ using precise definition of limit. Also find if $g$ is continuous at any rational $x$ or not.
Let us suppose that $x \to 0^+$. So for every $\epsilon$ we have to find a delta such that whenever $0<x<\delta$, $|\frac{2}{x - \sqrt{2}}| < \epsilon$
Now for positive $x$ close to zero we get
$\frac{2}{\sqrt{2} - x}<\epsilon$. Solving we get $0<x<\frac{\sqrt{2}\epsilon}{\sqrt{2} + \epsilon}$.
So we get $\delta = \frac{\sqrt{2}\epsilon}{\sqrt{2} + \epsilon}$.
Now let $x \to 0^-$
For negative $x$ close to zero we get
$\frac{\sqrt{2}x}{x - \sqrt{2}} < \epsilon$. Now if $\epsilon > \sqrt{2}$ then the above inequality is satisfied for all $x$. And if $\epsilon < \sqrt{2}$ then solving we get $\frac{\sqrt{2}\epsilon}{\epsilon - \sqrt{2}} < x < 0$. So we get $\delta = \frac{\sqrt{2}\epsilon}{\epsilon - \sqrt{2}}$. Am i correct?

Comment: Please show us a little bit of your work, and explain what it is you don't understand. This community is willing to help, but is most helpful (sometimes, only helpful) if you put some effort into solving a problem yourself first, and show that you've done so.

Answer (score 2):

I won't give you the answer (see my comment to your question above), so I'll just ask you some questions to help you on your way:

What is the "precise definition of limit" that you have to work with? (Presumably it has something to do with something like "For all $\varepsilon > 0$"...) What are the components of the definition of "limit" that correspond to this problem? Once you specify those and show some more work, see if you aren't able to "plug and chug" the solution. Same thing with the problem of continuity: use the $\varepsilon$, $\delta$ stuff and show us what you come up with.

Answer (score 1):

$x\mapsto \frac2{x-\sqrt2}$ being continuous as a function of $\mathbb R\setminus\{\sqrt2\}$, it also is continuous on the smaller domain $\mathbb Q$. This also implies that $\lim_0 g=g(0)=\sqrt 2$. I will leave the proof using the precise definition of limit to you!